# Converting array of objects for sorting in javascript?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, foreach

I'm trying to create a sortable list in my view. Each row entry is stored as an object in an array, and the string values are messing up the sorting.

The code is in Angularjs.

I've tried multiple different methods of creating the list, and while the sort function for the list works, the values themselves are sorted incorrectly. I believe this is because most of the values that are sorted incorrectly are **strings** and not integers.

Example of the data:

```
$scope.Info = { length 14
Object {InformationID: 100, fiscalYear: 2019, Number: "9", endDate: "2019-11-09T00:00:00" …
...}}
```

Code that I tried:

```
$scope.Info = {};
$scope.number = [];

ContractsService.getInformation()
.then(function (results) {
    $scope.Info = results.data;
    angular.forEach($scope.Info, function (value) {
        $scope.number.push(value.Number);
    }
}

$scope.save = function (Detail) {
[not needed in example]
```

The loop display for view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="Detail in Info | orderBy:rfrorder.Orderby:rfrorder.reverse">
```

I need to do save validation for the $scope.number to make sure the number isn't already used, so having those fields separate is fine. But for the rest, I'm pretty sure I have to **loop through the forEach and convert the string fields**, then somehow use the converted values as objects in the view.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the `Number` field from string to number:

```
$scope.Info.forEach(_ => _.Number = (+_.Number));
```

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)